# Is a two way content sync possible with Sitecore & Content Hub CMP

Tags: content-hub, cmp

We have `Content Collections` in `CMP` that are used in an external non-Sitecore application.

I understand, if we use the [Sitecore Connect for CMP](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sitecore-cmp/30/sitecore-connect-for-sitecore-cmp/sitecore-connect-for-sitecore-cmp.html), whenever a `Content Collection` is created in CMP, content items will be auto created under buckets in Sitecore.

Is it possible to create/update items in CMS and they will reflect in CMP?

Comment: Not with the CMP Connector

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are asking is not OOTB with the Content Hub/XP connector. Sitecore Connect will be a perfect fit for this scenario as you can create automation workflows easily that you can sync both CMP and XP/XM.

If you don't have Sitecore Connect, this would have to build custom.